# multiple requests to make an item in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I've come across a complicated case.

I have to make 3 get requests in order to make `Product` items.

1. `product_url`
2. `category_url`
3. `stock_url`

First, I need a request to `product_url` and a request to `category_url` to fill out the fields of `Product` items. I then need to refer to `stock_url`'s response to determine whether to save or discard the created items.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

In my spider,

```
def start_requests(self):
    product_url = 'https://www.someurl.com/product?'

    item = ProductItem()
    yield scrapy.Request(product_url, self.parse_products, meta={'item':item})

def parse_products(self, response):
    # fill out 1/2 of fields of ProductItem
    item = response.meta['item']
    item[name] = response.xpath(...)
    item[id] = response.xpath(...)

    category_url = 'https://www.someurl.com/category?'
    yield scrapy.Request(category_url, self.parse_products2, meta={'item':item})

def parse_products2(self, response):
    # fill out rest of fields of ProductItem
    item = response.meta['item']
    item[img_url] = response.xpath(...)
    item[link_url] = response.xpath(...)

    stock_url = 'https://www.someurl.com/stock?'
    yield scrapy.Request(stock_url, self.parse_final, meta={'item':item})

def parse_final(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']

    for each prod in response:
        if prod.id == item['id'] & !prod.in_stock:
            #drop item
```

**Question:** I was told before to handle the item-dropping logic in the pipeline. But whether I drop an item or not depends on making another GET request. Should I still move this logic to the pipelines/ is this possible without inheriting scrapy.Spider?

Comment: You should ask only 1 question per ticket! If you get 2 separate answers on each question, which one will be accepted?

Comment: @Andersson oops, noted.

Comment: Looks like you removed both questions in your edit.

Comment: are you not able to get category and stock information after you get into the product in the first request

Comment: @LandOwner I need all 3 requests to yield the content shown on the browser. product response shows every item whether they're in stock or not so I need stock response as well, and category response is needed b/c the individual product's url is a combination of category1, category 2, and product id, but category 1 is not included in product response.

Comment: @stranac fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the item dropping logic to the pipeline is probably the best design.

You can use the (undocumented) scrapy engine api to download requests in a pipeline. Example assuming the stock info for all items can be accessed from a single url:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks


class StockPipeline(object):
    @inlineCallbacks
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        req = scrapy.Request(stock_url)
        response = yield spider.crawler.engine.download(req, spider)
        # extract the stock info from the response
        self.stock_info = response.text

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # check if the item should be dropped
        if item['id'] not in self.stock_info:
            raise DropItem
        return item
```

If there is a separate, per-item url for stock info, you'd simply do the downloading in `process_item()` instead.

Comment: All the stock info is in one page, so this is perfect. Thanks so much!